# Code format to set selected value in dropdown

Tags: php

I'm new to php development and I'm struggling to write a code which will check condition to set selected value in drop down

```
 while ($row = $result_departments->fetch_assoc()) {
        $dept_info = array(
            'name'  => $row['dpt_name'],
             'id'    => $row['dpt_id']
        );
        $departments.= '<option value="'.$dept_info['name'].'" name="'.$dept_info['name'].'">'.$dept_info['name'].'</option>';

      }
return $departments;
```

While populating $departments i want to add condition `if $dept_info['name']=="XYZ" selected=="selected"` How can do that? I'm not able to write proper syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a simple if:

```
$departments.= '<option value="'.$dept_info['name'].'" name="'.$dept_info['name'].'"';

if ($dept_info['name']=="XYZ")
    $department.= ' selected="selected"';

$department .='>'.$dept_info['name'].'</option>';
```

The second way would be ternary operator:

```
$departments.= '<option value="'.$dept_info['name'].'" name="'.$dept_info['name'].'"';   
$department.= ($dept_info['name']=="XYZ"?' selected="selected"':null);
$department .='>'.$dept_info['name'].'</option>';
```

Comment: You should also probably escape any unknown values in generated HTML using PHP's `htmlspecialchars` function.  http://php.net/htmlspecialchars

Comment: Again i wrote it one line like and it's working $departments.= '<option '.(($dept_info['name']=="AVO")?'selected="selected"':'').' value="'.$dept_info['name'].'" name ="'.$dept_info['name'].'">'.$dept_info['name'].'</option>';

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 while ($row = $result_departments->fetch_assoc()) {
    $dept_info = array(
        'name'  => $row['dpt_name'],
         'id'    => $row['dpt_id']
    );
    $select_it = ($dept_info['name']=="XYZ") ? 'selected' : '';

    $departments.= '<option $select_it value="'.$dept_info['name'].'" name="'.$dept_info['name'].'">'.$dept_info['name'].'</option>';

  }
return $departments;
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple if/else should do the trick.

```
while ($row = $result_departments->fetch_assoc()) {
    $dept_info = array(
        'name'  => $row['dpt_name'],
        'id'    => $row['dpt_id']
    );
    if(dept_info['name'] == "XYZ") {
        $departments.= '<option value="'.$dept_info['name'].'" name="'.$dept_info['name'].'" selected="selected">'.$dept_info['name'].'</option>';
    } else {
        $departments.= '<option value="'.$dept_info['name'].'" name="'.$dept_info['name'].'">'.$dept_info['name'].'</option>';
    }
}
return $departments;
```